# Give admin_menu permission to specific users

Tags: admin, admin-menu, capabilities

I created a admin menu for my Wordpress website.
The capabillity / rules are set to manage_options. Now I want give permission to another user that is only an editor.

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

To grant access to the menu for users with Editor role, in place of `manage_options` use `publish_pages` as the capability.

To be able to guide you in the future, use the breakdown of capabilities listed in this page below. Pick a capability that is present only in the roles you're targeting.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/